# ASP.net 3.5 Send Web Page e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need a source code in C# or VB to send a web Page (inside a div) by e-mail, is it secure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your exact problem? Have you done any research yet? "Give me the codez" type of questions are usually not very well received here on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 2):

see [Send Email using ASP.NET formatted in HTML](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP-Code/Send-Email-using-ASPNET-formatted-in-HTML/)